# Using external CSS programmatically

Tags: java, css, eclipse, birt

I want to use an external css when executing the BIRT report via a Java application. I've come along with a few articles which sets the css at runtime over

`design.getDesignHandle().addCss("someCss.css");`

but it seems that it's deprecated. I'm using BIRT 4.4.2. Any suggestions how I could set a css file at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it.

First of all you have to make sure to USE the css file and not to import it.
After that you could set the css properties via the Property Editor.
The external CSS must have the same structure as the file you have declared before.
After that you can use the external CSS with the code below:

```
ReportDesignHandle report = (ReportDesignHandle)design.getDesignHandle();
report.addCss(report.openCssStyleSheet("pathToCSS/someCss.css"));
design.setDesignHandle(report);
```